# package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID

Tags: codenameone

Am trying to include GCM as native bundle. This runs as a background service but i cant get the build to compile successfully. I have android.playService.gcm=true as build hint. But i get the folliwng errors. It seems nothing in com.google.android.gms is being picked up. I have also enabled gradle build.

```
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaInstanceIDListenerService.java:15: error: package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
                                 ^
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaInstanceIDListenerService.java:16: error: package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;
                                 ^
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaInstanceIDListenerService.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public class RixmaInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
                                                    ^
  symbol: class InstanceIDListenerService
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class GcmPubSub
  location: package com.google.android.gms.gcm
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:17: error: package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
                                 ^
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaGcmListenerService.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class GcmListenerService
  location: package com.google.android.gms.gcm
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaGcmListenerService.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
public class RixmaGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
                                             ^
  symbol: class GcmListenerService
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaInstanceIDListenerService.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        startService(intent);
        ^
  symbol:   method startService(Intent)
  location: class RixmaInstanceIDListenerService
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RixmaInstanceIDListenerService.java:28: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            ^
  symbol:   class InstanceID
  location: class RegistrationIntentService
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable InstanceID
  location: class RegistrationIntentService
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE
  location: class GoogleCloudMessaging
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        ^
  symbol:   class GcmPubSub
  location: class RegistrationIntentService
/tmp/build6570310071572581493xxx/RixmaM/src/main/java/com/rixma/mobile/RegistrationIntentService.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable GcmPubSub
  location: class RegistrationIntentService
```

Please point me where i might be going wrong.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old flag uses play services version 6.5.* the above were introduced on version 7.5 if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1):

We temporarily disabled the Gradle build functionality as covered [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/android-gradle-build-status-minor-changes.html).

There were just too many regressions, so for now it should be back to the old gplay services flag.

Comment: Yes... the thing is even with old flag, it doesnt not spcifically accept these classes: 
com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;